# Devolver respuesta AJAX a otra funcion

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo dos funciones

Primera función:

```
sendRequest: function () { 
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: xtremeSearchUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
        data = this.searchBP();
        if (data == false) {

        }else{

        }
    },error{

    }});
    }
```

Segunda función:

```
searchBP: function () {
    var $url = "/bP";
    var $data = {url: window.location.pathname};
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $url,
        data: $data,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            return true;
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(status);
            console.log(error);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Tengo entendido que ajax se ejecuta asincronamente y al poner el async en false pausa toda la pagina, lo que necesito hacer es que cuando llame la función searchBP() no se ejecute nada más hasta que devuelva el true o el false y manejar según esa respuesta otro bloque de codigo en sendRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu función `searchBP` no retorna nada. Cuando haces `data = this.searchBP();` data no tiene el valor con que se resuelve `searchBP` sino que es simplemente `undefined`.

La manera correcta sería que `searchBP` retornara una promesa (jQuery.ajax retorna promesas)

```
searchBP: function () {
    var $url = "/bP";
    var $data = {url: window.location.pathname};
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $url,
        data: $data
     }).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
       return true;
     }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.status);
        console.log(err.statusText);
        return false;
     });
}
```

y entonces podrías usarla en `sendRequest` como

```
sendRequest: function () { 
  var _this = this; // para preservar la instancia de tu objeto
  jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: xtremeSearchUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
           _this.searchBP()
             .then(function(response) {
                if (response == false) {
                  console.log('searchBP es false');
                } else {
                  console.log('searchBP es true');    
                }
           });

    },error{

    }});
}
```

De todos modos debieras acostumbrarse a usar `then` y `catch` al ejecutar `jQuery.ajax` en vez de usar `success` y `error` que funcionan como callbacks y no adhieren al estandar de uso de promesas.

ojo que `catch` se usa desde jQuery 3. En jQuery 2.x se usa `fail`.

Answer (score 0):

Ya tu misma te respondiste. Haz tu primera funcion que no sea asyncrona con `async: false`, no realizara la segunda hasta llegar al success.

```
sendRequest: function () { 
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: xtremeSearchUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {
        data = this.searchBP();
        if (data == false) {

        }else{

        }
    },error{

    }});
    }
```

Comment: Es una mala práctica desactivar la asincronía, de hecho jQuery desde 
 la versión 1.8ya considera async: false "deprecated"

Comment: @PabloLozano Exactamente eso estaba haciendo, la desactive pero me salio que ya esta "deprecated"